# Blue-Green System: How to handle databases?

Tags: blue-green-deployment

I deployed two different versions of application to two eks clusters, blue and green. I plan to use route53 weighted routing policy to switch between blue and green. The microservices inside blue and green eks clusters immediately reading and updating databases once I deployed the application at blue and green. We can only have one application accessing database at one time. How to do it?

Comment: You have two EKS cluster, you should probably be using two RDS instances as well.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you.